# Comparar resultados da pesquisa MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estou precisando comparar o resultado de uma ***query*** para não repetir o resultado.

Por exemplo:
tenho no cadastro de unidade o seu cod e a velocidade, porem posso ter 2 situações:

1) mais de uma ocorrência para a mesma unidade e velocidades diferentes, e preciso que seja listado somente a ocorrência da velocidade maior.

```
cod  - velocidade
100  - 128
100  - 512
```

como resultado da pesquisa preciso listar somente a de maior valor:
100 - 512

2) posso ter também o retorno de mais ocorrências com a mesma informações, porem preciso listar somente uma delas:

```
cod - velocidade
105 - 512
105 - 512
105 - 512
```

e preciso listar somente 1x:
105 - 512

Como posso estar fazendo estas verificações?

Comment: Felipe, bem vindo ao [pt.so], aqui não alteramos o título para resolvido, apenas aceitamos a resposta que nos ajudou e votamos naquelas que consideramos boas ou úteis. eu editei o título para adequá-lo. Qualquer dúvida, faça uma visita ao [tour] ou [help]. Recomendo também uma [visita neste post](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Não precisa adicionar [resolvido] no título da pergunta, aqui é feito de outra forma, marque um `V` em baixo da resposta que você resolveu o problema ou que te ajudou mais, aproveite e veja [porque e como aceitar um resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/91)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Felipe utilize função de agregação do SQL.

```
SELECT COD, MAX(VELOCIDADE 
  FROM TABELA
  GROUP BY COD
```

Pronto. O sql agrupará por código todas as velocidades e exibirá somente a maior.

[Funções group by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

[group by](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

[Exemplos de group by](http://www.devmedia.com.br/exemplos-com-group-by-e-com-a-clausula-having-totalizando-dados-sql-server-2008-parte-2/19839)

Answer (score 2):

Na questão 1 você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT MAX(velocidade) AS velocidade FROM tabela WHERE cod = 100;
```

Na questão 2 você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cod, velocidade FROM tabela WHERE cod = 105 AND velocidade = 512
```

Comment: Acho que ele queria uma solução única para os vários casos de testes.

Comment: a solução pode ser separada sim, pois são 2 consultas diferentes e um determinado COD.
Num primeiro momento consulto somente pela unidade e após, Clicando na unidade pesquiso pelos seus detalhes, logo estou trabalhando com 2 consultas.

Vou aplicar o que foi posto aqui e ver o resultado. Lhes manteri informados.